# JSF2 how to create custom ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

In JSF2 how to create custom event, that will be triggered from javascript? In JSF2 component I would like to be able to use:

```
<f:ajax  event="customEvent" listener="#{bean.customEventListener}"/>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "triggered from Javascript"? What's the concrete functional requirement?